# Add filename as column header when combining multiple files

Tags: r

I am combining 1 column of data from multiple/many text files into a single CSV file. This part is fine with the code I have. However, I would like to have after importing the filename (e.g., "roth_Aluminusa_E1.0.DPT") as the column header for the data column taken from that file. I know, similar questions have been asked but I can't work it out. Thanks for any help :-)

Code I am using which works for combining the files:

```
files3 <- list.files()  
WAVELENGTH <- read.table(files3[1], header=FALSE, sep=",")[ ,1]  
TEST9 <- do.call(cbind,lapply(files3,function(fn)read.table(fn, header=FALSE, sep = ",")[ , 2]))  
TEST10 <- cbind(WAVELENGTH, TEST9)
```

Comment: Please re-format code, now it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to add column names to TEST10. This assumes the column name you want for the first column is `files3[1]`

```
colnames(TEST10) <- c(files3[1], files3)
```

In case you want to keep the name of the first column as is, then we add the desired column names before binding WAVELENGTH with TEST9.

```
colnames(TEST9) <-  files3
TEST10 <- cbind(WAVELENGTH, TEST9)
```

Then you can write to a csv as usual, keeping the column names as headers in the resulting file.

```
write.csv(TEST10, file = "TEST10.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi Juan Bosco. Thanks so much. It works, but with one hitch. The names are beginning from the first column and replacing the column header of the first column "WAVELENGTH". I have tried to edit it to work from second column, but can't figure it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you add the column names to TEST9 before binding it qith WAVELENGTH. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much. Works a treat. You make it seem so easy!